# Having problems with a simple Instagram Scraper

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, instagram, screen-scraping, urllib

i am pretty new to all the programming stuff and I am learning Python for my social engineering project. So really sorry if you will hit your own forehead.

So now i was looking at a tutorial to scrape certain information from a certain instagram page. Lets say f.e. i wanted to extract info from [www.instagram.com/nbamemes](http://www.instagram.com/nbamemes)

I am getting a problem in Line 12 "IndentationError: expected an indented block". So i have googled that, but i just dont get the Code. Where are my placeholders which i need to place info from myself.

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl
import json

class insta_Scraper_v1:

def getinfo (self, url):
html = urllib.request.urlopen('www.instagram.com/nbamemes', context=self.ctx).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
data = soup.find_all ('meta', attr={'property': 'og:description'})

text = data[0]
user = '%s %s %s' % (test[-3], text[-2], text[-1])
followers = text[0]
following = text[2]
posts = text[4]
print ('User:', user)
print ( 'Followers:', followers)
print ('Following:', following)
print ('Posts:', posts)
print ('-----------------------')

def mail(self:
self.ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
self.ctx.check_hostname = False
self.ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

with open('123.txt') as f: 
    self.content = f.readlines()
self.content = [x.strip() for x in self.content]
for url in self.content:
    self.getinfo(url)

if __name__ == '__main__'
obj = insta_Scraper_v1()
obj.main()
```

I used a Tutorial for programming this. However I dont get the whole thing right. Its not completely beginner friendly and I seem to need help. Again sorry for this super beginners question.

beste regards,

lev

Comment: Where did you copy that from? Indentation is important in python

Comment: Too many errors in your code. I fixed them but I think you need to start with the very basics of python first.

Comment: hi guys, thanks for your response and help. I used this to: https://www.promptcloud.com/blog/how-to-scrape-instagram-data-using-python/

Comment: @KostasCharitidis Please do not edit questions to fix the problem. Questions about common problems should just be immediately closed as duplicates. Questions with "too many errors" typically should be closed as Needs More Focus, if they aren't all fundamentally the *same* problem. If there is a question that merits an answer, answer it, don't fix the code in place. That defeats the purpose of the Q&A format.

Answer (score 0):

In the future, it would be useful to share the error message produced by your code. It includes the line at which the error has occurred.

Based on the code you provided, I can see that you did not indent the code inside your functions. After the function declaration `def`, you need to indent all code inside it

So from:

```
def getinfo (self, url):
html = urllib.request.urlopen('www.instagram.com/nbamemes', context=self.ctx).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
data = soup.find_all ('meta', attr={'property': 'og:description'})
```

To:

```
def getinfo (self, url):
    html = urllib.request.urlopen('www.instagram.com/nbamemes', context=self.ctx).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    data = soup.find_all ('meta', attr={'property': 'og:description'})
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Youll hear prolly more tickets from me in the future. Will provide the error log in the future!

Answer (score -1):

Indentations are the block separators in python. Below is the indented code. Whenever you are using the condition loops , def , class you are creating a block. In order to define that you have to indent the code using spaces . Usually a tab space is been preferred , but even a single space also works fine .

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl
import json

class insta_Scraper_v1:

    def getinfo (self, url):
        html = urllib.request.urlopen('www.instagram.com/nbamemes', context=self.ctx).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        data = soup.find_all ('meta', attr={'property': 'og:description'})

        text = data[0]
        user = '%s %s %s' % (test[-3], text[-2], text[-1])
        followers = text[0]
        following = text[2]
        posts = text[4]
        print ('User:', user)
        print ( 'Followers:', followers)
        print ('Following:', following)
        print ('Posts:', posts)
        print ('-----------------------')

    def mail(self:
        self.ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
        self.ctx.check_hostname = False
        self.ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

    with open('123.txt') as f: 
        self.content = f.readlines()
        self.content = [x.strip() for x in self.content]
        for url in self.content:
            self.getinfo(url)

if __name__ == '__main__'
obj = insta_Scraper_v1()
obj.main()
```

Ref : [Geeks For Geeks : Indentation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/statement-indentation-and-comment-in-python/#targetText=To%20indicate%20a%20block%20of,code%20a%20statement%20belongs%20to.)

Thanks

Comment: Thanks alot for your response! Clarified my failure :D!